# g++ missing on Amazon Linux AMI-2016.09 (Nominatim configure - no library found)

Tags: amazon-web-services, g++

Trying to set up OSM Nominatum and I am getting the following error during `./configure`

```
checking for proj headers in /usr/include... not found
checking for proj projection library... no
configure: error: required library not found
```

I ensured that `proj` and `proj-devel` were installed, but still getting the error. I read the answer [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/26798/error-during-nominatim-configure-no-library-found), which says to install `gcc-c++`, which I did, and I am still getting the same error above. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Provide the relevant lines from config.log which configure writes.

Comment: and you have obviously run `yum provides g++` and `yum whatprovides g++`  (or `gcc-c++`) as appropriate and saw that there were no available packages, then chose to ask this question because finding and adding the appropriate repository did not work correctly?  And also followed the steps from Amazon at this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html with no success?

Comment: Yes, `yum provides */g++` comes back with `No matches found`.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, figured it out. Downloaded the package from the AMI yum repo:

```
$ yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp gcc-c++
```

And then checked the contents of the file:

```
$ rpm -qlp gcc-c++-4.8.3-3.20.amzn1.noarch.rpm
(contains no files)
```

I believe that the package should *probably* create the symlinks, but it contains nothing, so it does nothing. Checking, I see that the package `gcc48-c++` is installed. Looking at the contents of the package, I see the following files:

```
$ rpm -ql gcc48-c++ | grep bin
/usr/bin/c++48
/usr/bin/g++48
/usr/bin/x86_64-amazon-linux-c++48
/usr/bin/x86_64-amazon-linux-g++48
```

Alright, so `g++` does not exist in `/usr/bin` but `g++48` does. Let's fix that:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/g++48 /usr/bin/g++
```

Now, running `./configure` and everything works as expected.

Comment: A friendly suggestion here - if it took you 5 minutes to solve the problem and answer your own question, perhaps you should hold off posting questions a touch longer, unless you're aiming to provide Q&A style help to others.

Comment: @Tim I was posting the question simply so I could answer it. That way if anyone in the future runs into the same issue, there's now a resource online which answers the question.